# Equivalence of conditions for torsions of links to be defined

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

The torsion of a link complement $S^3 \setminus L$ is defined in terms of the twisted chain complex $C_*(S^3 \setminus L; \rho)$, where $\rho : S^3 \setminus L \to \operatorname{GL}_k(\mathbb{k})$ is a representation of the link complement into the group of matrices over a field $\mathbb{k}$. (For the usual Reidemeister torsion/Alexander polynomial, $\rho$ is the representation sending each meridian to a variable $t \in \operatorname{GL}_1(\mathbb{Q}(t))$, but more generally we can consider nonabelian representations.)

For the torsion to be defined, the complex $C_*(S^3 \setminus L; \rho)$ needs to be acyclic.
There are two conditions usually given in the literature. One is that there is some meridian $x$ with $\det(\rho(x) - I_k)$ nonzero. Another is related to the reduced Burau representation. If $L$ is represented as the closure of a braid $\beta$ on $n$ strands, then we have $n$ meridians $x_1, \dots, x_n$ corresponding to the strands of $\beta$. The second condition says that $C_*(S^3 \setminus L; \rho)$ is acyclic if $\det(\rho(x_1 \cdots x_n) - I_k)$ is nonzero.

Either of these conditions is sufficient, but is either necessary? Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that $\det(\rho(x)-I_k) \neq 0$ is sufficient for $C_*(S^3 \setminus L;\rho)$ to be acyclic. Write $X_L:=S^3 \setminus L$. Let $\omega \in S^1 \setminus \lbrace 1 \rbrace$ and take the one-dimensional representation $\rho \colon \pi_1(X_L) \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ that maps each meridian to $\omega$. This way $\det(\rho(x)-I_1)=\omega-1 \neq 0$. However, I believe that $H_1(X_L;\rho)$ is zero if and only if $\Delta_L(\omega) \neq 0$ (the dimension of $H_1(X_L;\rho)$ is the nullity $\eta_L(\omega$)). Consequently, if $\omega$ is a root of $\Delta_L$, then I think that $C_*(X_L;\rho)$ is not acyclic.

So I think that the condition is necessary but not sufficient: the complex is acyclic if and only if all the $H_i(X_L;\rho)$ vanish. Your condition basically controls $H_0(X_L;\rho)$. If the complex is acyclic, then the $H_0$ must vanish which should imply that $\det(\rho(x)-I_k) \neq 0$.

Now to braids. From now on, $L=\widehat{\beta}$ is a braid closure and $\rho \colon F_n \to GL_k(\mathbb{k})$ is a representation of the free group that extends to a representation of $\pi_1(X_L).$ For the same reason as above, I'm not sure the condition is sufficient. I don't think it is necessary either. Assume $L$ is a knot, that $\beta$ has $n=3$ strands and that $\omega^3=1$. I am taking the same $1$-dimensional representation as above. Now $C_*(X_L;\rho)$ is acyclic ($\det(\rho(x)-I_1)=\omega-1 \neq 0$ and $\Delta_L(\omega) \neq 0$ because for a knot $K$, $\Delta_K(t)$ does not have roots that are prime powers of unity). However, by my choice of $\omega$, I have $\det(\rho(x_1x_2x_3)-I_1)=w^3-1=0$.

In particular, the conditions are not equivalent: for that example $\det(\rho(x)-I_k) \neq 0$ but $\det(\rho(x_1x_2\cdots x_n)-I_k) = 0$.

Finally, a topological remark. Write $D_n$ for the $n$ times punctured disc. The free group $\pi_1(D_n)$ has the $x_i$ as its generators, so morally $\partial D_n$ "is" $x_1x_2\cdots x_n$. Now $X_L$ can be obtained from the exterior of the closure of the braid in the solid torus, by adding on an extra solid torus. Equivalently, $X_L=X_{\widehat{\beta} \cup \partial D_n} \cup (D^2 \times \partial D_n)$. The torsion of $D^2 \times \partial D_n$ is your $\det(\rho(x_1x_2\cdots x_n)-I_k)$. Now the resulting Mayer-Vietoris sequence with twisted coefficients relates the acyclicity of $C_*(X_K;\rho)$ to $\det(\rho(x_1x_2\cdots x_n)-I_k)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think my confusion was caused by the twisted Alexander polynomial literature, where the representations are always tensor products of representations and the abelianization map, viewed as a map to $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm1}]$. Then the eigenvalues are multiples of $t$, hence transcendental, so they cannot be roots of the Alexander polynomial.

Comment: However, it does seem like you can still extract a well-defined torsion when $\det(\rho(x_i) - I) \ne 0$, even if the complex isn't acyclic. It might be that there's a canonical choice of basis of $H^1$ that is implicitly being chosen.

Comment: The context for this question is Proposition 3.6 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.01133), which might need to be modified in light of your answer.

Comment: Regarding your first comment. Take $\rho \colon \pi_1(X_L) \to \mathbb{Q}(t)$ mapping each meridian to $t$. If $L$ is an $n$-component boundary link, then its Alexander polynomial is identically zero and the dimension of $H_1(X_L;\mathbb{Q}(t))$ is $n-1$ and yet $\det(\rho(x)-I_1))=t-1 \neq 0$.